# How to refresh React UI after new changes?

Tags: reactjs

Hi every time I make changes to my React UI I need to hit shift refresh to see the new changes. Is there way to do this with out having to explain to my user to use shift refresh?

I would assume having a lower browser cache time would help, but that still requires shift refresh if you want to see the immediate changes.

Comment: Are you using a bundler like webpack or parcel? Is this a create-react-app? Usually bundlers will compile your app under a slightly different filename to prevent the browser from using a cached version when the content changes.

Comment: Using create-react-app-ts.

Comment: Have you read [Creating a Production Build](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/production-build) in the docs?

Comment: Ok so most files are hashed and static... What I can I do then? Set lower max age?